# Merging elements of a list of case classes

Tags: scala, monoids

I have the following case class:

```
case class GHUser(login:String, contributions:Option[Int])
```

And a list of such elements:

```
val list = List(
    List(GHUser("a", Some(10)), GHUser("b", Some(10))), List(GHUser("b", Some(300)))
  ).flatten
```

And now I would like to merge all elements such that all contributions are added together for the same user. At first I thought I could apply a Monoid to my case class, like this:

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}

trait Monoid[A] extends Semigroup[A] {
  def empty: A
}

case class GHUser(login: String, contributions: Option[Int])

object Main extends App {
  val ghMonoid: Monoid[GHUser] = new Monoid[GHUser] {
    def empty: GHUser = GHUser("", None)

    def combine(x: GHUser, y: GHUser): GHUser = {
      x match {
        case GHUser(_, None) => GHUser(y.login, y.contributions)
        case GHUser(_, Some(xv)) =>
          y match {
            case GHUser(_, None) => GHUser(x.login, x.contributions)
            case GHUser(_, Some(yv)) => GHUser(x.login, Some(xv + yv))
          }
      }
    }
  }


  val list = List(
    List(GHUser("a", Some(10)), GHUser("b", Some(10))), List(GHUser("b", Some(300)))
  ).flatten

  val b = list.groupBy(_.login)
  val c = b.mapValues(_.foldLeft(ghMonoid.empty)(ghMonoid.combine))

  println(c.valuesIterator mkString("\n"))
  // GHUser(a,Some(10))
  // GHUser(b,Some(310))
}
```

An it works, but I feel like I am not following Monoid Laws, as it is required that all user have the same `login` (For that reason I did the `groupBy` call.

Is there a cleaner solution?

## Update

Rereading my question, it seems like I do not want a `Monoid` but a `Semigroup`, am I right?

Comment: These seems very heavyweight compared to a simple `groupBy` - `map` - `fold`.

Comment: I do not know why, but I can't call map on the groupby: `b.map(x => x)`, x appears to be `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupMapReduce()` (Scala 2.13) handles most of what you need.

```
list.groupMapReduce(_.login)(_.contributions){case (a,b) => a.fold(b)(n => Some(n+b.getOrElse(0)))}
    .map(GHUser.tupled)
//res0 = List(GHUser(a,Some(10)), GHUser(b,Some(310)))
```

The `Reduce` part is a bit convoluted but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution:

```
list.groupBy(_.login).map{
  case (k, v) =>
    GHUser(k, Some(v.flatMap(_.contributions).sum))
}
```

This will give `Some(0)` for users with no contributions. If you want `None` in this case it looks more ugly:

```
list.groupBy(_.login).map{
  case (k, v) =>
    val c = v.flatMap(_.contributions)
    GHUser(k, c.headOption.map(_ => c.sum))
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, `Some(0)` is OK.